# Search for a particular SharePoint user programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007

I've an InfoPath form that the filler needs to specify people. A workflow later assigns tasks to these people. What I'm looking for is a people picker like what SharePoint has for user fields, but that I can use in InfoPath. I've already designed a form to do this where the filler can put in a name or email and the form will list results from the site.allusers group.

The problem is, what if the person that needs to be added into the form has never accessed this particular site collection before. Their account isn't going to be listed in the AllUsers list.

Where in the object model can I search for a user that is able to authenticate with SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the OTB one in InfoPath and configure it to point to your SharePoint environment?

http://www.sharepointassist.com/2009/02/27/adding-a-contact-selectorpeople-picker-to-an-infopath-form/

If your running MOSS with AD integration, then it should automatically retrieve everyone that's in your domain if AD synch is enabled.

Comment: Actually I just discovered this control today. Funny how easy it is to miss things like this if you don't get the google search quite right.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem here is that even if you do find a list of users, the workflows won't trigger any actions if the users don't exist in the User Information List.

If the users don't exist in the User Information List, then you won't be able to find them via the SharePoint object model because they don't exist in SharePoint. You will have to find them some other way.

So basically, it depends on how the authentication is configured on your SharePoint server :

If you are using FBA, then the users who can authenticate with SharePoint must exist in a SQL database somewhere. [Membership.Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider%28VS.90%29.aspx) will give you a hook on your FBA membership provider (whether it's a SqlMembershipProvider or something else). You can then use methods like

```
Membership.Provider.GetUser(username)
```

to see if a user exists. You can also loop through your users or find all the existing usernames which you could then display in your people picker.

If you are using windows authentication, you will have to look in your AD to find the potential users. The [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) object is what you'll need. I imagine that only users from a certain AD group can access SharePoint? If so, then isolate that group with the DirectoryEntry object, loop through the users and you will have your data source for the people picker.

As I said above though, either method will give you the possible users, but it won't make the workflow work if the users have not logged in. Workflows will only work properly with users that do exist in the User Information List.

When someone picks a user that doesn't exist in SharePoint, you will probably have to create it via code. A safe way to do this is with the [SPWeb.EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspxsite.).

> Checks whether the specified login
>   name belongs to a valid user of the
>   Web site, and if the login name does
>   not already exist, adds it to the Web
>   site.site.

So really, to answer your question, nowhere. You need to look for them where they could be coming from.